# How do you model an action in RAML

Tags: action, raml

I would like to understand what is the best approach for modeling an action on a resource using RAML.

E.g. I have the following resource definition in RAML:

```
/orders:
  type: collection
  get:
    description: Gets all orders
  post:
    description: Creates a new order

  /{orderId}:
    type: element
    get:
      description: Gets a order

    put:
      description: Updates a order

    delete:
      description: Deletes a order
```

Now for an order I would like to model an "approve" action. Is there a best practice of doing this with RAML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could PUT or PATCH for setting some "Approval" to true in your model.
- You could think about the approval as a resource. For example:

  ```
  /orders:
    type: collection
    get:
    post:
    /{orderId}:
      type: element
      get:
      put:
      delete:
      /approval:
        post:
        get:
        ...
  ```

It's not a RAML best practice. It's more related with how do you represent your model in REST.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [PATCH request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) with a "patch document" that raises the approved flag on an order.